# Using OpenNLP in Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, opennlp

I'm trying to write a (hopefully) simple script that will parse a short paragraph.  I need it to do sentence detection and tokenization in two separate steps so that the user can edit the output of the sentence detection before moving on to the next step.  This is to manually catch any sentences that can be broken down into smaller complete sentences.  The prose I will be working with will be pretty short, so the sentence detection and editing should be trivial.  Once the user is happy with the sentence output file, a tokenizer should further break down each line.  The results will then go into an XML file.  The ultimate result should be something like:

Original Input: "John likes Mary and Mary likes John."

Edited Sentence Output:

```
John likes Mary and Mary likes John.
John likes Mary
and
Mary likes John.
```

Final Output:

```
<fullText>
<snippet value="John likes Mary and Mary likes John.">
<snippet value="John likes Mary">
<snippet value="John"/>
<snippet value="likes"/>
<snippet value="Mary"/>
</snippet>
<snippet value="and"/>
<snippet value="Mary likes John.">
<snippet value="Mary"/>
<snippet value="likes"/>
<snippet value="John"/>
<snippet value="."/>
</snippet>
</snippet>
</fullText>
```

I've come across [OpenNLP](http://opennlp.apache.org/), which seems like it has both the sentence detector and tokenizer that I need, but I'm new to Groovy and I'm having trouble figuring out how to use these tools in my script.  I tried to work with the code found [here](https://gist.github.com/nagaimasato/1178725), but haven't been able to get it to work.  I have the following code in my script, but I get an error that TokenizerModel cannot be found.

```
@Grapes(
  @Grab(
    group='org.apache.opennlp', 
    module='opennlp', 
    version='1.5.1-incubating'
  )
)
import opennlp.tools.tokenize.*

static TokenizerModel tokenizerModel
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can include it in your *BuildConfig.groovy* instead.
Make sure that you have `mavenCentral()` in your repositories block,  and in the dependencies add the dependency for OpenNLP which you can find [here](http://opennlp.apache.org/maven-dependency.html).

Should look something like this:

```
repositories {
    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    mavenCentral()
} 
dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.opennlp:opennlp-tools:1.5.2-incubating'
}
```